# xmlPath Cannot get specific objects to list from xml

Tags: java, xml, rest-assured

I recently started using rest-assured to test some xmls. Here is an example:

```
<activity>
    <shopping>
        <category type="groceries" label="chocolate" />
        <category type="groceries" label="chocolate" />
        <category type="present" label="chocolate" />
        <container number="eight" color="green" />
    </shopping>
    <shopping>
        <category type="groceries" label="chocolate" />
        <category type="groceries" label="chocolate" />
        <category type="present" label="chocolate" />
        <container number="eight" color="green" />
    </shopping>
    <shopping>
        <category type="groceries" label="chocolate" />
        <category type="groceries" label="chocolate" />
        <category type="present" label="chocolate" />
        <container number="eight" color="green" />
    </shopping>
</activity>
```

What I wanted to achive here, is check if for every shopping, there is a container number = "eight" and then check if every container has color = "green". Here is the code:

```
assertThat(xmlPath.getList("activity.shopping.list().container.findAll{it.@number == 'eight'}.@color", String.class), everyItem(equalTo("green")));
```

this works perfectly fine, when I debug this I get exactly what I wanted to achive :

```
        List <String> lista = xmlPath.getList("activity.shopping.list().container.findAll{it.@number == 'eight'}.@color", String.class);
```

This is a three element list, where every element equals "green".

But when I try to check if for every shopping, there is a category type = "present" and then check if every of these categories has label = "chocolate", I recive an empty list:

```
        List <String> lista2 = xmlPath.getList("activity.shopping.list().category.findAll{it.@type == 'present'}.@label", String.class);
```

Any ideas what I am missing or how solution should look like? Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

It's a guess, but perhaps you need a `.list()` after `.category`?

P.S. you probably meant to call the variable `container`...

Comment: I changed containter to container for sake of clarity, thank you. Well that is true that `.list()` after category return list with desired object, but not with desired effect. It will not check if in each shopping there is desired category. It would check if in all shoppings there are desired categories. For example if I would remove `<category type="present" label="chocolate" />` from one shopping and move to another, the effect with this solution will be the same. I am looking for solution, where effect would be different with this example.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution. First of all I want to show why your suggestions did not satisfied me. That is true, that it would work for showed example, but if xml would look like this it would not do the job.

```
<activity>
    <shopping>
        <category type="groceries" label="chocolate" />
        <category type="groceries" label="chocolate" />
        <container number="eight" color="green" />
    </shopping>
    <shopping>
        <category type="groceries" label="chocolate" />
        <category type="groceries" label="chocolate" />
        <category type="present" label="chocolate" />
        <category type="present" label="chocolate" />
        <container number="eight" color="green" />
    </shopping>
    <shopping>
        <category type="groceries" label="chocolate" />
        <category type="groceries" label="chocolate" />
        <category type="present" label="chocolate" />
        <container number="eight" color="green" />
    </shopping>
</activity>
```

```
    @Test
    public void test3() {
        final XmlPath xmlPath = new XmlPath(TestXML2);
        assertThat(xmlPath.getList("activity.shopping.category.findAll{it.@type == 'present'}.@label", String.class), everyItem(equalTo("chocolate")));
    }
```

in this case test is still passing, even if in not every shopping we have `<category type="present" label="chocolate" />`

what I managed to figure out is to map shoppings on a list, and then check categories in for loop:

```
    @Test
    public void test4(){
        List<Node> shoppings = new XmlPath(TestXML2).getList("activity.shopping.list()");
        for (Node categories : shoppings) {
            String val  = categories.getPath("category.findAll{it.@type == 'present'}.@label");
            assertThat(val, equalTo("chocolate"));
        }
    }
```

with above example this test will fail as expected, because it check correctly if in every shopping there is desired category with desired attributes.